# Issue with finding the averages of multiple rows at once

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I am currently tasked with hundreds of rows of data for a project. I need to take the average of each row, but there are way too many rows for me to do by each individual row. Is there any way to take the average of each of these rows all at once? I really do not want to spend hours doing this tedious calculation.

I attached a picture to give you an idea of what I'm asking for.

[image: 1]

Comment: Also, when I press enter it does automatically return the average formula based on the first couple of averages I have already done, but I do not want to sit for an hour pressing the enter button hundreds of times either.

Answer (score 0):

- paste this in **E2** cell:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA((QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D), 
   "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , IF(LEN(A2:A),
   "avg(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")), "select Col2")))
  ```

  [image: 0]